# Foreign key in the database

Tags: python, sql, django

This is a database for use in Brazil, so the language is Portuguese. Translation:

- Pessoa = Person
- Veiculo = Vehicle

I use this database to keep track of vehicles in a parking lot with monthly vehicle records.

My problem is one of permutations: *Each person could have many vehicles, but each vehicle belongs to only one person.*

## How do I make sure that, when making an entry, vehicles are only registered in the name of the Person (Pessoa), not the Vehicle (Veiculo)?

I'm using the SqlLite 3 from Django

Foreign key in the database

Models.py

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, blank=False)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)

class Veiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    ano = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, )
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    observacoes = models.TextField(blank=False)

class Mensalista(models.Model):
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
         blank=False)
    inicio = models.DateField(blank=False)
    validade = models.DateField(blank=False)
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    valor_mes = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can not register a Person in the Monthly Table that she only accepts vehicles that this person owns, with this code I can register Person X with Person's Car Y and the Database is accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store the Person (Pessoa) in the Monthly (Mensalista) model as it is already defined by the vehicle. Having an instance of `Mensalista` (let's say `m`) you can access the Vehicles's owner simply by doing `m.veiculo.proprietario`

If, for some reason (clarity, cleanness or whatever) you want to have a `proprietario` property on your `Mensalista` model you could simply add the following:

```
@property
def proprietario(self):
    return self.veiculo.proprietario
```

To sum up you could change your `Mensalista` model to the following:

```
class Mensalista(models.Model):
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey(Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    inicio = models.DateField(blank=False)
    validade = models.DateField(blank=False)
    # The next is not necessary
    # proprietario = models.ForeignKey(Pessoa, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    valor_mes = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=False)
    pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)

    @property
    def proprietario(self):
        return self.veiculo.proprietario
```

To clarify a bit more, the models as you have them are what is called denormalized (you can read more about normalization and denormalization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). Essentially your models are redundant since you have a `ForeignKey` to `Person` on both `Vehicle` and `Monthly` but you want that the person in `Monthly` is the same as the person in  `Vehicle`. You can save yourself some trouble by erasing the reference to `Person` in your `Monthly` model. In this way you don't need to enforce that both reference to `Person` coincide as there is only one reference to `Person`.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm really new and I did not understand what it would look like in the code

Comment: I edited the answer so you can get a better look at what it would like. Anyway I believe you should take some time to understand what these models generate at the databse level

Comment: thank you very much, I was able to understand the error of logic, thank you very much for your patience and kindness to help me.

Comment: thank you very much, I was able to understand the error of logic, thank you very much for your patience and kindness to help me.

Comment: Great! If you feel this question was answered then please mark it as so and don't leave it open. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to model this scenario a bit different. As your model `Vehicle` is already related to your model `Person`, your attribute proprietario in the model `Mensalista` is not necessary and this sounds enough to solve your problem.
Notice that once you can get a `Person's` attributes due the relationship it has with you model `Vehicle`, it doens't make sense (in my humble opinion and inside this context) to explicitly relate a `Person` to `Mensalita`, if you already have an implictly relatioship between them through your model `Vehicle`:

```
mensalita = Mensalita.objects.get(pk=this_object_id);
veiculo = mensalita.veiculo;
pessoa = veiculo.proprietario; //You've got your Person without problems.
```

However, in a context where two people share the same vehicle and this car is eventually parked by some of this drivers, this attribute would be helpful but yet not the best solution for your problem.

I hope I understood correctcly your problem. Please let me know if it's everything clear enough for you. I'll be glad to help you out if I missed something.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm really new and I did not understand what it would look like in the code

Comment: I believe @ivissani has clarified this last point very well. Any futher explanation would be redudant and maybe confusing.
If find yourself frequently struggling with this concepts, taking some time to have a look at Django's documentation, precisely the model layer, is a good idea. I've already had explored Django's world a bit in the past and its documentation is quite friendly. Here's the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)